# Find a WPF Combobox item using SelectedValue from Binded Combobox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, selecteditem, selectedvalue

Can Anyone help me to find the Combobox Item using value property. The combobox is binded to a Dataset.
Here is my code.

XAML Code

```
ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Margin="12,23,0,0" Name="cbxDesignation" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="Desig_Code" SelectedItem="Desig_Name"
```

C# Code behind.

```
//Populate Designation

<i> strSQL = "SELECT Desig_Code, Desig_Name FROM Desig_Master";

            dsCommon = CDTier.ReturnDataSet(strSQL);

            cbxDesignation.DataContext = dsCommon.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            cbxDesignation.DisplayMemberPath = dsCommon.Tables[0].Columns["Desig_Name"].ToString();
            cbxDesignation.SelectedValuePath = dsCommon.Tables[0].Columns["Desig_Code"].ToString();
            if (dsCommon.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                cbxDesignation.SelectedIndex = 0;
            dsCommon.Dispose();
</i>
```

Based on the employee selection, I want to Display his Designation. In the Database I have only Designation Code (Desig_Code) which i have mapped in SelectedValuePath.

How can I achieve this?

I have the `cbxDesignation.SelectedValue` as below

```
cbxDesignation.SelectedValue =  (dsMaster.Tables[0].Rows[0] 
["Desig_Code"].ToString() != "") ? dsMaster.Tables[0].Rows[0]
["Desig_Code"].ToString() : "0";
```

Please help anyone.....

Thank you.

Comment: Anybody there to help me?

Comment: HELLO ANYBODY THERE TO HELP MEEEEEE...

Comment: Hello.................. I want to populate the employee definition form with all the details based on the selected employee ID from the grid. The emp designation combobox have Desig_descr as Displaymemberpath & Desg_Code as selectedvaluepath. Now based on the emp ID, I have got the Desig_Code from DB and I want to pickup & show the correct Desig_Descr in the combo Box.

Answer (score 0):

try using `cbxDesignation.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cbxDesignation.SelectedValue)` which should give you your `ComboBoxItem`.

alternatively you could use `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(cbxDesignation.SelectedIndex)` as an alternative

Comment: Hi Dean, Thx.. but I am getting null in the Item.. see here the below code I have used..    `ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)cbxDesignation.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cbxDesignation.SelectedValue);`

Comment: Ive edited the answer to show an alternative approach - hope it helps

Comment: Hi Dean... I think u didn't get my question correctly. I don't have the selected index with me. I have only Desig_code with me and I want to Display the corresponding designation in the Combobox.